# Is it possible to create a new web application and database on my Azure account from code?

Tags: .net, azure

I am writing an application that needs to abstract the business of setting up web application and SQL database instances on Azure on a single corporate account so that non-technical stakeholders can create hosted micro applications on the web.

The web application that will give our corporate users this ability is written in .NET MVC (C#) and will be running under the same corporate account on Azure.

Is there any sort of API that will allow me to create the new web application and SQL instances from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Azure Resource Manager Template is a JSON format file which defines all of the Azure infrastructure resources for a specific resource group or deployment. The template can be deployed with a single powershell command, or via a Visual Studio deployment task, eg:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm'))
  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile 
  -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile @OptionalParameter -Force -Verbose
```

The command above uses a template parameter file to define the inputs that will be used to name and locate the resources to be created, as well as a name of the actual resource group to deploy into. This resource group must already have been created, using the command

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction Stop
```

ARM Templates are idempotent, which means that no harm comes from deploying the template again if the resources already exist. The resource manager that carries out the deployment will be able to figure out if the resources already exist or not, and if they’re in the desired state (per the template and parameters provided), and will not execute any operations to change or deploy resources that are consistent. ARM Templates can contain functions to manipulate parameters and variables, and they’re used extensively throughout the EHI template to adhere to naming conventions, for example. A full list of the functions supported by templates can be found here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/

Ive blogged about how to build a Continuous deployment process with VSTS to Azure using ARM templates as well - the template in my walkthrough is for a website + SQL database, which is one of the "out of the box" templates provided with Visual Studio.  You don't have to use VS to do this, it just makes the process a little easier.  You can use notepad and command line if you like, or you can edit templates directly in the "templates" my.gallery in the azure portal.

[Continuous Deployment process of Infrastructure as code to an Azure Resource Group](https://russellyoung.net/2016/04/15/arm-cd-vsts/)

Answer (score 1):

I think Azure Resource Manager  is what you are looking for to provision resource pragmatically.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790568.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

And for sample template, you can reference from sample github repository

e.g 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-sql-database